# Click on a <h:commandLink> on a row from a modal screen

Tags: jquery, jsf

I have in JSF 2.2 a table (id `rangenTabel`). In this table I have the entries of a database table. Each row has a hidden `commandLink` to delete this row. Before I send this request to the bean on the server I want a confirmation from the user with the help of a modal screen. This modal screen is shown when the user clicks on an `<img>` in the row. Before I show the modal screen I want to replace the `onclick` attribute with the command to click on the right `commandLink`.

**What I have**

At this moment I am already able to replace tyhe `onclick` attribute with `alert('button clicked');` which causes another alert to pop up.

The table is in a form and looks like (I stripped out all other columns for readability):

```
  <h:form id="formRangen">
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-datatable display compact" id="rangenTabel">
      <colgroup>
        <col width="50px" />
      </colgroup>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <t:dataList var="rang" value="#{lijst}" rowIndexVar="idx">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h:commandLink action="#{natuur.verwijderRang(rang.rang)}" actionFor="formRangen" id="lnkDelete" /><img src="user-trash.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete" onclick="$('#btnDelete').attr('onclick','alert(\'button clicked\');');$('#bevestiging').modal('show');" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </t:dataList>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <ui:include src="confirmatie.xhtml">
      <ui:param name="confirmatietitel" value="Delete XXX" />
    </ui:include>
  </h:form>
```

The `button` on the is in the modal modal screen (defined in `confirmatie.xhtml`) and looks like:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="bevestiging" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="bevestiging" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div>
          <p class="pull-left"><img src="user-trash.png" /></p>
          <h3 id="teVerwijderen"></h3>
        </div>
        <br />
        <h4 class="text-center">Are You Sure?</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="btnDelete" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="return false;">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The output looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="nl" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"><!--

//--></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"><!--

//--></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"><!--

//--></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"><!--

//--></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><!--

        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#rangenTabel').dataTable( {
            "order": [[1, "asc"]],
            "columns": [
                      { "orderable": false },
                      { "orderable": true },
                      { "orderable": true }
                  ],
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "Alle"]],
            "language": {
              "paginate": {
                "first": "&lt;&lt;",
                "last": "&gt;&gt;",
                "next": "&gt;",
                "previous": "&lt;"
              },
              "lengthMenu": "_MENU_ rijen per pagina",
              "search": "Zoeken:",
              "zeroRecords": "Niets gevonden.",
              "info": "Pagina _PAGE_ van de _PAGES_",
              "infoEmpty": "Geen rijen beschikbaar.",
              "infoFiltered": "(gevonden uit _MAX_ rijen)"
            }
          } );
        } );
      
//--></script></head><body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="menu" class="row"><nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/natuur/index.jsf">Natuur</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/natuur/admin/parameters.jsf">Parameters</a></li>
          <li><a href="/natuur/rangen/rangen.jsf">Rangen</a></li>
          <li><a href="/natuur/gebieden/gebieden.jsf">Gebieden</a></li>
          <li><a href="/natuur/taxa/taxa.jsf">Taxa</a></li>
          <li><a href="/natuur/waarnemingen/waarnemingen.jsf">Waarnemingen</a></li>
          <li><a href="/natuur/fotos/fotos.jsf">Foto's</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="row">
      <div class="container"><form id="formRangen" name="formRangen" method="post" action="/natuur/rangen/rangen.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-datatable display compact" id="rangenTabel">
    <colgroup>
      <col width="50px" />
      <col width="60px" />
      <col />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Niveau</th>
        <th>Rang</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#" onclick="return myfaces.oam.submitForm('formRangen','formRangen:j_id_g:0:j_id_j');"><img src="text-x-generic.png" alt="Bekijken" title="Bekijken" /></a><a href="#" onclick="return myfaces.oam.submitForm('formRangen','formRangen:j_id_g:0:lnkDelete');" id="formRangen:j_id_g:0:lnkDelete"></a><img src="user-trash.png" alt="Verwijderen" title="Verwijderen" onclick="$('#teVerwijderen').text('???biologie.rang.osp;nl???');$('#btnDelete').attr('onclick','$(this).closest(\'#lnkDelete\').click();');$('#bevestiging').modal('show');" />
          </td>
          <td class="text-right">171</td>
          <td>???biologie.rang.osp;nl???</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#" onclick="return myfaces.oam.submitForm('formRangen','formRangen:j_id_g:1:j_id_j');"><img src="text-x-generic.png" alt="Bekijken" title="Bekijken" /></a><a href="#" onclick="return myfaces.oam.submitForm('formRangen','formRangen:j_id_g:1:lnkDelete');" id="formRangen:j_id_g:1:lnkDelete"></a><img src="user-trash.png" alt="Verwijderen" title="Verwijderen" onclick="$('#teVerwijderen').text('Ondersoort');$('#btnDelete').attr('onclick','$(this).closest(\'#lnkDelete\').click();');$('#bevestiging').modal('show');" />
          </td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
        </div>
        <div class="row"><div class="modal fade" id="bevestiging" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="bevestiging" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h2 class="modal-title">Verwijder Rang</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div>
            <p class="pull-left"><img src="user-trash.png" alt="Verwijderen" title="Verwijderen" hspace="10px" /></p>
            <h3 id="teVerwijderen"></h3>
          </div>
          <br />
          <h4 class="text-center">Zeker weten?</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button id="btnDelete" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="return false;">Verwijderen</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Annuleren</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
        </div><input type="hidden" name="formRangen_SUBMIT" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="mE5vSMv6UxfQzWZp/4ahdi+1n402A4UuPClyZ4G8Q2DaDNDB" /></form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8 footer">  Versie: 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT | Bouwdatum: 2016-03-04 20:57:05
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="modal" class="row">
    </div>
  </div></body>
</html>
```

**Question**

How do I change the `onclick` attribute of the `<button>` that it will execute the `commandLink` button on the same row as the one on which the `<img>` was clicked? It must use somehow the ID of the table (`rangenTabel`), the ID of the `commandLink` (`lnkDelete`), and the `rowIndexVar` (`idx`). And not to forget the correct usage of the $, (, ), #, and \'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks to @gurpreet-singh who did 99% of the work. Somehow the pagination made his solution fail on the elements that were not displayed on the first page.

Instead of putting the javascript in the `onclick` of a class I created the following function:

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  function confirmatie(deze, tekst){
    $('#teVerwijderen').text(tekst);
    var elem = $(deze).closest('td').find('.lnkDelete').first();
    $('#btnDelete').one('click',function() {
        $(elem).click();
    });
    $('#bevestiging').modal('show');
  }
  </script>
```

In the `onclick` of the `<img>` I added:

```
onclick="confirmatie(this, '#{rangtekst}');"
```

Now when I click the `<img>` the modal screen is displayed with the texts that I want and when I click on the `accept` button the `onclick` of the right `<h:commandLink>` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited:**

In jQuery closest() method only helps to find the ancestors. 
So used a combination of **closest()** and **find()** method to get the element which needs to be clicked.

More over no need to add the value into onclick attribute of html tag, preferably we can use jQuery to bind a click event on the button (say 'btnDelete').

```
$('.img_del').on('click', function(){
   var txt=$(this).closest('td').next().next().html();
   $('#teVerwijderen').text(txt);
   var elem = $(this).closest('td').find('.lnkDelete').first();
   $('#btnDelete').one('click',function() {
      $(elem).click();
   });
   $('#bevestiging').modal('show');
});
```

Code needs few modifications:

1. Change `<img src="user-trash.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete" onclick="$('#btnDelete').attr('onclick','alert(\'button clicked\');');$('#bevestiging').modal('show');" />`

to   `<img src="user-trash.png" alt="Delete" title="Delete" class="img_del" />`

2. Add the class="lnkDelete" to the 'lnkDelete' link.
3. Then try above script.

Comment: Not quite what I need. The `alert('\button clicked'\)` must be replaced by `lnkDelete.click()` where `lnkDelete` is referencing to the `lnkDelete` on the same row as the `<img>` on which was clicked. I will try `$(this).closest('#lnkDelete').click()`. I changed my question in the hope to be more clear.

Comment: yeah got that. So exactly when you click on delete Image of any row, then there is a common modal box which needs to be shown, now the thing is that if Yes is clicked in modal then it should determine which row'img was clicked. So can proceed further. Please confirm !!
Can you give html o/p of  whole form (id="formRangen") ? 
Or create a jsfiddle including these above pages ?

Comment: This is what I want. I changed my question and it contains a table with 2 rows. The image is not visible. Instead you can click on the word `Verwijderen` which is the `title` and `alt` of the `<img>`.

Comment: I have created a fiddle for that https://jsfiddle.net/cc7ncnxd/4/ . I have changed the jQuery version to 1.11.3 and bootstrap from 3.3.1 to 3.3.5 as modal() was not working with previous configurations.
IT seems working, check it once.

Comment: It works but not 100%. The datatables create a pagination. On the first page it works, on the next ones not. You also forgot to mention to add the `class="lnkDelete"` to the '`lnkDelete`' link.

Comment: Ok. I edited the answer. It should work on all pages. Might be you need to do some editing in code. If you have any other doubt you can ask.

Comment: I checked my source again but cannot find the problem. The table is 'paginated' with `dataTables.js` and it works on the first page but on the second page the `<img>` is no longer 'clickable'. Can this has something to do that the function is defined on load time (`window.onload=function(){$('.img_del').on('click'` etc.)?